# How to write this tail event as a member of the tail $\sigma$ field?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

For events $A_1, A_2, \dots$, the book I'm reading defines the tail $\sigma$-field as
$$
\bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} \sigma\{ A_{n+1}, A_{n+2}, \dots \}.
$$

I'm trying to understand what this "looks" like, so I have created the following example:

Let $A_n$ be the event that you get heads on the $n$-th flip of a fair coin. My conjecture is that the event of getting $10$ consecutive heads infinitely many times is in the tail $\sigma$ field. Let's call this event $A$. I've looked up examples online (none of which are fully satisfactory to me), and I think this is in the tail $\sigma$-field since whether or not $A$ occurs does not depend on the first $n$ flips, for any $n$.

What I want to do is figure out how you explicitly write $A$ as an element of the tail $\sigma$ field, in this particular example. I'm able to write it as an uncountable union of elements from $\sigma\{ A_1,A_2,\dots\}$, but $\sigma$-algebras aren't closed under uncountable unions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think this is in the tail $\sigma$-field since whether or not $A$ occurs does not depend on the first $n$ flips, for any $n$.

This argument suffices.

---

Writing your example out explicitly will get kind of hairy. I consider instead a simpler example, and hope you can get the idea. If $A$ is the event of getting infinitely many heads, then **for any finite $n$**,
$$A = \bigcap_{k \ge 1} \bigcup_{j \ge k} A_j = \bigcap_{k \ge n} \bigcup_{j \ge k} A_j \subset \sigma\{A_n, A_{n+1},\ldots\},$$
so it is in the tail $\sigma$-field.

For your example, you can probably do something similar by defining $B_n = A_n \cap A_{n+1} \cap \cdots \cap A_{n+9}$ for a run of $10$ consecutive heads.